# go:video tag with token links

Tags: video, facebook-opengraph, token, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to use the OG tags for my site and share videos. this works fine but then after a period of time the video link i share expires. the link is from cloudfront and is being set for a limited about of time 15 min. I have tried extending the time limit on the video to 36 hours after reading about Facebook scraping the page for new metadata every 24 hours but it doesn't get the new link. i also tried to force it https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
with no luck.

Does Facebook not update the video tag when it scrapes? Or am i missing some param?

```
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="<?php echo $version['height']?>" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="<?php echo $version['width']?>" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $pageMetaData['title']?>" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $pageMetaData['description']?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->Image->resize('/img/videos/'.$video['Video']['image1'], $width=200, $height=200, $aspect = true, $htmlAttributes = array(),$fulltag = false, $cut = false, $return = false);?>" />
<meta property="og:video" content="<?php echo urlencode($link)?>&autostart=true" />
```